# Why is PdfSharp creating borders around web links?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have the following function to create a weblink using PdfSharp:

```
    public static void AddWebLink(XGraphics gfx, PdfPage page, XFont font, string url, string text, int startX, int startY)
    {
        if (gfx == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("gfx");

        if (page == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("page");

        if (font == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("font");

        // Write out the text
        gfx.DrawString(text, font, XBrushes.Blue, new PointF(startX, startY));
        var stringSize = gfx.MeasureString(text, font);

        // Create the linked area
        // For some reason the Y of the rectangle needs to be startY minus the height
        startY -= (int)stringSize.Height;

        var rect = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(startX, startY, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height));
        var pdfRect = new PdfRectangle(rect);
        var annotation = page.AddWebLink(pdfRect, url);
        annotation.Opacity = 0; // Try and prevent it from rendering a box around the link in some viewers
    }
```

When the PDF is generated, everything is fine when viewed in Foxit Reader:

[image: Foxit Image]

However, Adobe Acrobat Reader 10 and 11 shows a black-thin border around the linked area:

[Acrobat http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/acrobat-bad.PNG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/acrobat-bad.PNG)

Unfortunately, since Acrobat Reader is more standard it's a requirement that it must look right in it.

Can someone clue me in as to why all of my link areas are getting borders in them in acrobat reader?

---

**Edit:** I tried to make the annotation invisible by both `annotation.Opacity = 0` and `annotation.Color = XColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);`.  The former did not work (border still appeared), the latter made the border white which doesn't 100% work because it creates oddities in some lines of text (like a white line cutting off the bottom of y's, p's, etc...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known problem.

The solution can be found here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6161#p6161

The frame is a bug in PDFsharp. It's a bug in Adobe Reader up to 10.0.3 not to display the frame.

**Update:** The bug was fixed a long time ago and links created with recent versions will not have frames around them.

Comment: Looks like I"ll need to compile PdfSharp and Migradoc for myself to fix this (since my project mixes both).  Thanks, I tried searching but couldn't find that post.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by:

1.) Downloading the latest release of PDFSharp from [CodePlex](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases)

2.) Modifying the PdfLinkAnnotations.cs line 120 from `new PdfLiteral("<</Type/Border>>");` to `new PdfLiteral("<</Type/Border/W 0>>");`.

3.) Compiling PDFSharp project

4.) Change your project that uses PDFSharp to use the freshly compiled .dll.

Hope this simple all inclusive explanation helps others.